# How to use get()to call on a variable in a function in R?

Tags: r, function, variables, get

I am trying to use get() in a function. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. The data is:

```
ID<-c("001","002","003","004","005","006","007","008","009","010","NA","012","013")
Name<-c("Damon Bell","Royce Sellers",NA,"Cali Wall","Alan Marshall","Amari Santos","Evelyn Frye","Kierra Osborne","Mohammed Jenkins","Kara Beltran","Davon Harmon","Kaitlin Hammond","Jovany Newman")
Sex<-c("Male","Male","Male",NA,"Male","Male",NA,"Female","Male","Female","Male","Female","Male")
Age<-c(33,27,29,26,27,35,29,32,NA,25,34,29,26)
data<-data.frame(ID,Name,Sex,Age)
```

It works in some codes like this:

```
FctPieChart <- function(data,Var){
  
  dVar <- data %>%
    filter(!is.na(get(Var))) %>%
    group_by(get(Var)) %>% #changes the name of the column to "`get(Var)`"
    summarise(Count = n()) %>%
    mutate(Total = sum(Count), Percentage = round((Count/Total),3))
}  
FctPieChart(data,"Sex")
```

And it doesn't work in some other codes like this:

```
FctPieChart <- function(data,var){
  x <- data %>% 
    select(get(var))
  x
  
}  
FctPieChart(data,"Sex")
```

It says:

```
<error/simpleError>
object 'Sex' not found
```

Does anyone know why?

Thank you very much in advance!

Best regards,

Stephanie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr::select()` you don't need to use `get()`. Instead just use`select(var)`

```
> FctPieChart <- function(data,var){
   x <- data %>% 
     select(var)
   x
 }  
> FctPieChart(data,"Sex")
      Sex
1    Male
2    Male
3    Male
4    <NA>
5    Male
6    Male
7    <NA>
8  Female
9    Male
10 Female
11   Male
12 Female
13   Male
```